# Wrapping multiple lines as a single unit

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Let's say I have two lines of text:

```
abcdefghi
123456789
```

If I put them in a very narrow window, then they might wrap as follows:

```
abcde
fghi
12345
6789
```

However, I want to ensure that I always keep a part of line 1 directly above line 2, like this:

```
abcde
12345
fghi
6789
```

You can imagine that the two lines are part of a combined unit, which is the thing that I want to wrap (rather than wrapping each line independently). I know this example may look silly, but the target application is for guitar tabs where it's important that all 6 lines of notes wrap together.

So far I have achieved this by using a monospace font and putting each "column" of characters into its own `<div>`, however this creates a *ton* of divs on real world examples and hurts page performance.

Is there a more elegant/performant way to accomplish this, e.g. with CSS?

**UPDATE:**

Here is a modified version of misatrincado's answer that basically accomplishes what I want:

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 2em;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  word-break: break-all;
}

.line {
  position: absolute;
  line-height: 4em;
}

.line2 {
  transform: translateY(1.5em);
  color: red
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <span class="line line1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</span>
    <span class="line line2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</span>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
 .circle {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-top: 4px solid;
    border-bottom: 4px solid;
  }
  .circle_1 {
    border-color: red;
  }
  .circle_2 {
    transform:translateY(-32px);
    border-color: green;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="circle circle_1" />
  <div class="circle circle_2" />
</div>
```

I think understood you.
you like this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUKOj.png)

Comment: Thank you, I had to tweak it a bit for the text-based scenario but it set me on the right track. I wish there was a more elegant approach than hard-coding classes for each "line" to handle the translateY amounts, and the overlapping of elements makes it hard to see what's going on in the DOM inspector. However, this is probably the closest thing to a solution with current browser APIs. I'll accept this for now and update my question with a fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function chunkString(str, length) {
  return str.match(new RegExp('.{1,' + length + '}', 'g'));
}

guitar = [
  '12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678',
    '-+--+--+-+-++--++-+--+--+-+-++--++-+--+--+-+-++--++-+--+--+-+-++--++',
  '-+--+-++-+-++-+---+--+-++-+-++-+---+--+-++-+-++-+---+--+-++-+-++-+--',
  '+-++--+-+++---+-++-++--+-+++---+-++-++--+-+++---+-++-++--+-+++---+-+',
  '+--+-+-+++-----+-+--+-+-+++-----+-+--+-+-+++-----+-+--+-+-+++-----+-',
  '-----------++---------------++---------------++---------------++----',
  '++-++-----+-+----++-++-----+-+----++-++-----+-+----++-++-----+-+----'
];

pixels_per_char = 20;
default_length  = Math.floor(Number(window.innerWidth) / pixels_per_char);

// assuming all strings are same length
total_lines_groups = Math.ceil(guitar[0].length / default_length);

// Chunking guitar strings in arrays
guitar.forEach( function (value, index) {
  guitar[index] = chunkString(value, default_length);
});

i = 0;
while (i < total_lines_groups) 
{
  to_insert = '<p>';
  guitar.forEach( function (entry) {
    to_insert += entry[i] + '<br>';
  });
  to_insert += '</p>';
  
  $('#result').append(to_insert);
  
  i++;
}
```

```css
body{
  font-family: 'Source Code Pro', monospace;
}

p{
  margin:2rem; 
  padding:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Code+Pro:ital,wght@1,300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: I am looking for something that is responsive to the window size rather than generating fixed-length lines

Comment: Added pixels_per_char variable for a responsive experience. Basically you can match pixels_per_char value with font size and you will have your strings responsive to the window size.

Comment: Was my answer useful?

Comment: It's getting closer, but I'm mainly looking for a responsive CSS solution rather than using Javascript. Your updated solution is only responsive to the initial window size — I'd need to add in logic to re-render everything when the window size changes, which may come with other bugs and edge cases. A CSS approach would handle that stuff automatically.